# Array manipulation in Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, csv

**The Scenario is as follows:**

I have a dynamically changing text file which I'm passing to a variable to capture a pattern that occurs throughout the file. It looks something like this:

```
my @array1; 
my $file = `cat <file_name>.txt`;
if (@array1 = ( $file =~ m/<pattern_match>/g) ) {
    print "@array1\n";
}
```

The array looks something like this:

```
10:38:49 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54 10:38:51 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54
```

From the above `array1` output, the pattern of the array is something like this:

```
T1 P1 t1(1) t1(2)...t1(25) T2 P2 t2(1) t2(2)...t2(25) so on and so forth
```

Currently, `/g` in the `regex` returns a set of values that occur only twice (only because the txt file contains this pattern that number of times). This particular pattern occurrence will change depending on the file name that I plan to pass dynamically.

**What I intend to acheive:**

The final result should be a `csv` file that contains these values in the following format:

```
T1,P1,t1(1),t1(2),...,t1(25) 
T2,P2,t2(1),t2(2),...,t2(25) 
so on and so forth
```

For instance: My final CSV file should look like this:

```
10:38:49,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
```

The delimiter for this pattern is `T1` which is time in the format `\d\d:\d\d:\d\d`

*Example:* `10:38:49`, `10:38:51` etc

**What I have tried so far:**

```
use Data::Dumper; 
use List::MoreUtils qw(part);
my $partitions = 2;
my $i = 0;
print Dumper part {$partitions * $i++ / @array1} @array1;
```

In this particular case, `my $partitions = 2;` holds good since the pattern occurrence in the txt file is only twice, and hence, I'm splitting the array into two. However, as mentioned earlier, the pattern occurrence number keeps changing according to the txt file I use.

**The Question:**

How can I make this code more generic to achieve my final goal of splitting the array into multiple equal sized arrays without losing the contents of the original array, and then converting these mini-arrays into one single CSV file?

If there is any other workaround for this other than array manipulation, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I considered Hash of Hashes and Array of Hashes, but that kind of a data structure did not seem to be healthy solution for the problem I'm facing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all you need is [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), which will work fine as long as you know the record size and it's constant

The data you showed has 52 fields, but the description of it requires 27 fields per record. It looks like each line has T, P, and t1 .. t24, rather than ending at t25

Here's how it looks if I split the data into 26-element chunks

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @data = qw/
    10:38:49 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54 10:38:51 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54
/;

while ( @data ) {
    my @set = splice @data, 0, 26;
    print join(',', @set), "\n";
}
```

### output

```
10:38:49,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
```

If you wanted to use [`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) instead of `splice`, the the `natatime` function returns an iterator that will do the same thing as the `splice` above

Like this

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/ natatime /;

my $iter = natatime 26, @data;

while ( my @set = $iter->() ) {
    print join(',', @set), "\n";
}
```

The output is identical to that of the program above

### Note

It is very wrong to start a new shell process just to use `cat` to read a file. The standard method is to undefine the input record separator `$/` like this

```
my $file = do {
    open my $fh, '<', '<file_name>.txt' or die "Unable to open file for input: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};
```

Or if you prefer you could use [`File::Slurper`](http://metacpan.org/module/File::Slurper) like this

```
use File::Slurper qw/ read_binary /;

my $file = read_binary '<file_name>.txt';
```

although you will probably have to install it as it is not a core module

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code works like a charm. Also learnt that I'm not supposed to use `cat` to read a file in this sort of a scenario. 
However, I have this question: I have tried out the following code to write the contents to a `CSV`
`open($output, '>', '19_file.csv') or die "Couldn't open file file.csv, $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { sep_char => ",", eol => "\n", binary => 1, quote_char => undef } );
foreach my $element ( @array2 ) { 
 $csv -> print ( \*$output, \@array2 );
} 
print "CSV file writing done \n";
close($output) or die "Couldn't close file properly";`

Comment: `@array2` is the `splice`d version of the original array. The output that I get in CSV is the last line of the array printed multiple times. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Ghost: If your `@array2` is the same as my `@set` (you really must choose better identifiers: the `@` says it's an array, and the name is a chance to explain its *purpose*) then it changes each time around the `while` loop (in fact, if you had *declared* it inside the loop as I did mine it wouldn't be accessible elsewhere) so you need to print its contents inside that loop too. But unless you're expecting your data to contain something more elaborate that just digits and colons then I would forget about `Text::CSV` and just `print join(',', @set), "\n"` as I did

Comment: My requirement is to get this `@set` outside of the `while` loop, and then print this data in `CSV`. That's why I'm using `Text::CSV` since this array doesn't contain anything except digits and colons. So, I have made a global declaration on almost all variables/arrays/hashes including `my @set;` . The problem I'm facing right now is conversion of `@set` into `CSV`.  My `CSV` looks something like this after using the code I've mentioned in my previous comment 
`19:03:48,782,45,41,45,51,45,49,45,41,45,67,45,70,45,44,38,38,38,45,38,45,38,38,38,48` Only this element is repeated multiple times

Comment: The rest of the elements don't seem to occur in the `CSV` at all. Can you please tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: @Ghost: What you say doesn't make sense. I have explained that with data like that there is *no need* to use `Text::CSV`, and that your code isn't working *because* you have declared `@array2` globally. My code works correctly as it stands; why can't you use it like that? Variables should be declared as *late* as possible, and usually at the point they are first used. If you are still having problems then you should ask a new question as I can't tell what your code looks like if you're not using what I have written

Comment: I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649479/issues-while-creating-csv-out-of-an-array-in-perl). Thanks for this answer. Upvoted and accepted.