# Issues while creating CSV out of an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

**Brief Description of my problem:**

I have an array which needs to be converted to `CSV`. I am facing problems with the desired output, and not the conversion itsef.

**My Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper; 

my (@first_set, @final_set); 
my $file = do {
    open my $fh, '<', '<file_name>.txt' or die "Unable to open file for input: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

@first_set = ( $file =~ m/<regex>/g)  ;
while ( @first_set ) {
    @final_set = splice @first_set, 0, 26;
    open(my $output, '>', 'mpc7_file.csv') or die "Couldn't open file file.csv, $!";
    my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { sep_char => ",", eol => "\n", binary => 1, quote_char => undef } );
    foreach my $element ( @final_set ) { 
        $csv -> print ( \*$output, \@final_set );
    }   
    close($output) or die "Couldn't close file properly";
}
```

**Contents of `@final_set`:**

```
10:38:49 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54
10:38:51 788 56 51 56 61 56 59 56 51 56 80 56 83 56 50 45 42 45 50 45 50 45 43 45 54
```

**Contents of the `CSV` file:**

```
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
```

**Desired Output:**

My `CSV` file should contain the `@final_set` (each element separated by comma).

```
10:38:49,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
10:38:51,788,56,51,56,61,56,59,56,51,56,80,56,83,56,50,45,42,45,50,45,50,45,43,45,54
```

**Question:**

Where am I going wrong? I'm not really able to understand my mistake. Please help.

EDIT:

Even if I move the `CSV` file creation block outside of `while` loop, the output is still the same.

Comment: Contents of `@final_set` is the actual array contents, which incidentally should be `CSV` contents as well, only that the array needs to be converted to `CSV`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I see what you're doing. The problem is that `@final_set` changes each time around the `while` loop, and whether you declare it globally like that or locally as you should you still need to print its contents each time it changes

There's also no need to use `Text::CSV` with such simple data. As you can see, every variable is declared *at its point of first use*, which is best practice in most languages

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in_file  = '<file_name>.txt';
my $out_file = 'mpc7_file.csv';

my $data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $in_file or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for input: $!};
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my @first_set = $data =~ /<regex>/g;

open my $out_fh, '>', $out_file or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for output: $!};

while ( @first_set ) {
    my @final_set = splice @first_set, 0, 26;
    print $out_fh join(',', @final_set), "\n";
}

close $out_fh or die qq{Unable to close "$out_file": $!};
```

Comment: I realized that `Perl v5.14` isn't standard across my organization/company. So, I end up with this syntax error:  `Perl v5.14.0 required--this is only v5.8.9, stopped at example.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at example.pl line 7.`
Any workaround for this?

Comment: @Ghost: Okay, that means you  can't use `autodie` as I suggested and  have to check the `open` calls by hand. I've updated my solution